# ORMLite and Other ORM Options for Android

Tags: android, database, orm, data-access-layer, ormlite

Been looking for an ORM for Android. Personally I think its a setback these days for an SDK not to have an ORM. In this aspect iOS SKD is ahead.

I came across ORMLite, which looks quite simple to use.

My concern is compatibility w/ various SDK levels in Android (have a requirement to stay reverse compatible down to 2.2 SDK LEVEL 9)

Any other ORMs I  should consider?

Any pitfalls I should watch out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) its open source freeware.

It has good developer support & many application running on ORMlite.

another is [greenDao](http://greendao-orm.com/) library. Its very easy to use. Here is a [comparison](http://software-workshop.eu/content/comparing-android-orm-libraries-greendao-vs-ormlite)

Answer (score 0):

ORMLite is great. You are able to do necessary database operations without writing sql. ORMLite works with older android versions such as gingerbread so I wouldn't be concerned about that.

This [section of the documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started) will help you get going, or if you prefer a video tutorial, this one is very helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beb-n2yq0kM

The only drawback to it that I can think of is that it's a small community so the support and documentation is a bit sparse at times. That said, the creator (Gray) is active on Stack Overflow and he is likely to be around to help if you have more advanced issues.